# Partial Match On Left Join (Oracle, SQL Query)

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two separate oracle database tables with a key that I need to join (Left Join to table 1).
The table1 has records with multiple keys in the same field as shown in the below sample.

```
1303233,
1302246,
1303113 / 1339100 / 1303797,
1308897 / 1302818
```

Table2 Only has one key per record

```
1303233,
1302246,
1303113,
1339100,
etc...
```

How would I join table1 to to table2 with a 'partial match'?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "partial match".  Why does your data model store multiple values in a column?

Comment: I do not control the management of the sources, and instead need to determine how to link the data anyways. By 'Partial Match', I mean to join by each key found in the listings. so if there was 3 in table1 listed for one record, it would be joined 3 times to table 2

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your data model.  Multiple values should not be stored in a single string.  They should be separate rows in a junction/association table -- or perhaps a JSON array or other data structure.

But, you can use any comparison you like for joining, so you could use:

```
select . . .
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on ' / ' || t1.col || ' / ' like '% / ' || t1.col || ' / %'
```

However, your effort should go into fixing the data model.